# OS X 10.8.3 root user account permissions corrupted

Tags: macos, root, macports

I'm running into a root permissions issue on OS X 10.8.3. This is manifesting itself in various forms.

It became clear after trying to execute a self-update of MacPorts. The following issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15780321/macport-selfupdate-fails-code-23-xcode-command-line-tools-are-installed highlights the error seen.

XCode and the XCode command line utilities are installed and the root user is enabled.

The key thing is that I can't make changes as root as root doesn't seem to have the right permissions. I've tried chown'ing and chmod'ing anything in /etc and /etc/local but I always get "Operation not permitted"

I've followed all the normal resolutions. Disk Utility -> Repair Permissions,  Enable/Disable the root user, change the root user p/w, power-cycle the machine.

```bsh
bash-3.2$ chmod 775 base.tar
chmod: Unable to change file mode on base.tar: Operation not permitted
bash-3.2$ ls -la
total 129744
drwxr-xr-x  10 root  admin       340  8 Apr 15:17 .
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  admin       102  8 Apr 12:38 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin   9453803  8 Apr 12:30 PortIndex
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin       512  8 Apr 12:31 PortIndex.rmd160
drwxr-xr-x  24 root  wheel       816 31 Jan 17:30 base
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin   3594240  8 Apr 15:01 base.tar
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin       512  8 Apr 15:01 base.tar.rmd160
drwxr-xr-x  51 root  wheel      1734  8 Apr 15:17 ports
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin  53360640  8 Apr 15:01 ports.tar
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin       512  8 Apr 15:01 ports.tar.rmd160
bash-3.2$ whoami
root
bash-3.2$
```

At this stage I'm considering re-installing but would prefer to fix this rather than start again.

Output of id is :

```
uid=504(root) 
gid=0(wheel) 
groups=0(wheel),
402(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),
401(com.apple.access_screensharing),
1(daemon),
2(kmem),
3(sys),
4(tty),
5(operator),
8(procview),
9(procmod),
12(everyone),
20(staff),
29(certusers),
33(_appstore),
61(localaccounts),
504(admin),
98(_lpadmin),
100(_lpoperator),
204(_developer),
403(com.apple.sharepoint.group.2)
```

output of dscl . read '/Users/root'

```
bash-3.2$ dscl . read '/Users/root'
AppleMetaNodeLocation: /Local/Default
GeneratedUID: FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA00000000
NFSHomeDirectory: /Users/root
Password: ********
PasswordPolicyOptions:
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>failedLoginCount</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>failedLoginTimestamp</key>
    <date>2001-01-01T00:00:00Z</date>
    <key>lastLoginTimestamp</key>
    <date>2001-01-01T00:00:00Z</date>
    <key>passwordLastSetTime</key>
    <date>2013-05-27T07:39:18Z</date>
</dict>
</plist>

PrimaryGroupID: 0
RealName: root
RecordName:
 root
 BUILTIN\Local System
RecordType: dsRecTypeStandard:Users
SMBSID: S-1-5-18
UniqueID: 504
UserShell: /bin/bash
```

Comment: One thing to try would be booting from the restore partition (or, DVD, if your computer is 10.6 or older), and running disk utility to repair permissions on the main partition.

Comment: Also, make sure the permissions on /etc/sudoers is -r--r----- (440).

Comment: The shell doesn't seem to recognize your root-ness, hence the `$` instead of `#`. What's the output of `id`?

Comment: comments taken onboard and question amended with output

Comment: Why does root have uid 504 on your system?

Comment: @Kent, Tried restarting with cmd+R and using disk utility. No effect.

Comment: @patrix, root as part of group admin(504) would be normal right?

Comment: Nothing about that is normal. What's the output of the following: `dscl . read '/Users/root'`?

Comment: @DanielBeck, output of command in question.

Comment: I have `uid=0(root) gid=0(wheel) groups=0(wheel)` here.

Comment: Try this:

http://superuser.com/questions/511082/major-permission-repair-needed-on-mac-os/823893?stw=2#823893

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow you created another user named *root* who does not have root permissions (which might have overridden the default `root` account), or changed root's user ID. `root` should have UID 0. Maybe the instructions for *Enable/Disable the root user, change the root user p/w* you followed were incorrect.

You can try specifying UID 0 explicitly by running `sudo` as follows:

```
sudo -u '#0' <command>
```

---

`dscl` is the command-line utility for managing user accounts (among other things). Output of `dscl . read '/Users/root'` should look similar to this by default:

```
AppleMetaNodeLocation: /Local/Default
GeneratedUID: FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA00000000
NFSHomeDirectory: /var/root
Password: *
PrimaryGroupID: 0
RealName:
 System Administrator
RecordName: root
RecordType: dsRecTypeStandard:Users
SMBSID: S-1-5-18
UniqueID: 0
UserShell: /bin/sh
```

You could *try* to re-set everything by running `dscl . change '/Users/root' 'UniqueID' '504' '0'`, and hope that `sudo` works for this. This could break even more though – I've only tested it with the `UserShell` key.

Comment: thanks for this. I wasn't able to change with dscl but went through directory utility instead. Got the gist of what you were suggesting. My root user is now '0'. The dscl output has some kerberos info but I assume you filtered this out from your post for security reasons?

Comment: I filtered nothing, but additional entries might not be a problem -- it looks like the UID is the important issue here. It looks like that line might be the hash of the password (my root doesn't have that).

Comment: OK. I've removed some of the superfluous info but as you say it doesn't make much odds. The key thing here was definitely the UID. Anyway thanks again for the help. Much appreciated. I'm a happy user again. Was really fearing having to re-install

Comment: Thanks for this, it fixed my issue. For those just copy/pasting the command, don't forget to change `'504'` with the actual current id of the root user. Also, don't forget it's `UniqueID` and not `UniqueId` (that typo cost me 10 minutes of confusion)